# clSetKernelArg returning error code -49

Tags: opencl, pyopencl

I have written the following C++ code. At `clSetKernelArg( kernel, 8, sizeof( cl_mem ), (void *) &mob_whdis );`, it returns `error code -49`, and I don't understand why. Everything else runs properly.  Can anyone help me?

```
cl_mem mob_X = NULL;
cl_mem mob_Y = NULL;
cl_mem mob_Z = NULL;
cl_mem mob_WAT = NULL;
cl_mem mob_POL = NULL;
cl_mem mob_FSW = NULL;
cl_mem mob_nop = NULL;
cl_mem mob_nofsw = NULL;
cl_mem mob_whdis = NULL;
cl_mem mob_watwp = NULL;
cl_mem mob_watp = NULL;
cl_mem mob_distp = NULL;
cl_mem mob_watww = NULL;
cl_mem mob_watw = NULL;
cl_mem mob_distw = NULL;
cl_program program = NULL;
cl_kernel kernel = NULL;
cl_uint ret_num_devices;
cl_uint ret_num_platforms;
cl_int err;
float whdis=3.5;
mob_X = clCreateBuffer( context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, na * sizeof(float), NULL, &err );
mob_Y = clCreateBuffer( context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, na * sizeof(float), NULL, &err );
mob_Z = clCreateBuffer( context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, na * sizeof(float), NULL, &err );
mob_WAT = clCreateBuffer( context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, now * sizeof(int), NULL, &err );
mob_POL = clCreateBuffer( context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, nop * sizeof(int), NULL, &err );
mob_FSW = clCreateBuffer( context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, now * sizeof(int), NULL, &err );
mob_nop = clCreateBuffer( context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(int), NULL, &err );
mob_nofsw = clCreateBuffer( context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(int), NULL, &err );
mob_whdis =  clCreateBuffer( context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(float), NULL, &err );
mob_watwp = clCreateBuffer( context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(int) * now * 40, NULL, &err );
mob_watp = clCreateBuffer( context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(int) * now * 40, NULL, &err );
mob_distp = clCreateBuffer( context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(float) * now * 40, NULL, &err );
mob_watww = clCreateBuffer( context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(int) * now * 40, NULL, &err );
mob_watw = clCreateBuffer( context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(int) * now * 40, NULL, &err );
mob_distw = clCreateBuffer( context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(float) * now * 40, NULL, &err );
err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer( command_queue, mob_X, CL_TRUE, 0, na * sizeof(float), X, 0, NULL, NULL );
err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer( command_queue, mob_Y, CL_TRUE, 0, na * sizeof(float), Y, 0, NULL, NULL );
err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer( command_queue, mob_Z, CL_TRUE, 0, na * sizeof(float), Z, 0, NULL, NULL );
err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer( command_queue, mob_WAT, CL_TRUE, 0, now * sizeof(int), wat, 0, NULL, NULL );
err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer( command_queue, mob_POL, CL_TRUE, 0, nop * sizeof(int), pol, 0, NULL, NULL );
err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer( command_queue, mob_FSW, CL_TRUE, 0, now * sizeof(int), fsw, 0, NULL, NULL );
err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer( command_queue, mob_nop, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(int), &nop, 0, NULL, NULL );
err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer( command_queue, mob_nofsw, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(int), &nofsw, 0, NULL, NULL );
err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer( command_queue, mob_whdis, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float), &whdis, 0, NULL, NULL );
err_check( err, "clSetKernelArg" );
err = clSetKernelArg( kernel, 0, sizeof( cl_mem ), (void *) &mob_X );
err = clSetKernelArg( kernel, 1, sizeof( cl_mem ), (void *) &mob_Y );
err = clSetKernelArg( kernel, 2, sizeof( cl_mem ), (void *) &mob_Z );
err = clSetKernelArg( kernel, 3, sizeof( cl_mem ), (void *) &mob_WAT );
err = clSetKernelArg( kernel, 4, sizeof( cl_mem ), (void *) &mob_POL );
err = clSetKernelArg( kernel, 5, sizeof( cl_mem ), (void *) &mob_FSW );
err = clSetKernelArg( kernel, 6, sizeof( cl_mem ), (void *) &mob_nop );
err = clSetKernelArg( kernel, 7, sizeof( cl_mem ), (void *) &mob_nofsw );
err = clSetKernelArg( kernel, 8, sizeof( cl_mem ), (void *) &mob_whdis );

    // Step 11: Execute OpenCL kernel in data parallel
size_t worksize[] = { now, 1, 1 };
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel( command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL, worksize, 0, 0, 0, 0 );
err_check( err, "clEnqueueNDRangeKernel" );
// Step 12: Read (Transfer result) from the memory buffer
```

Comment: I took the liberty of rewording your question. I hope that's OK. :)

Comment: A start would be [figuring out what `-49` actually means](http://www.google.de/#gs_rn=19&gs_ri=psy-ab&cp=9&gs_id=57&xhr=t&q=opencl+error+codes&es_nrs=true&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&oq=opencl+er&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48705608,d.Yms&fp=1becc00280c7e15&biw=1920&bih=1034).

Answer (score 2):

The error -49 is `CL_INVALID_ARG_INDEX`. You should check your opencl kernel source arguments.

Also, In your code you should `clCreateProgramWithSource` with the OpenCL source code of your program, `clBuildProgram` to compile and link it, and then use `clCreateKernel` to get a valid kernel reference. And then you can use `clSetKernelArg` properly.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick counter-question:

mob_whdis is a device buffer that is sizeof(float).  This means there is a single float value in global memory.  Global memory has a large performance hit when reading and writing.  Can you instead using a private const such as:

float mob_whdis = 0.0f;
...
SetKernalArg(kernel, 8, sizeof(float), &mob_whdis);

This places a float constant in all of your kernels that is in private memory which is very fast, much faster than Global.

Same goes for mob_nofsw and mob_nop.